# probability distribution estimation from correlated samples

Tags: probability-theory, parameter-estimation

I am looking to solve the following estimation problem. Consider a blackbox where (given below) given an input X, its N observations are recorded as output.

These observations are denoted by $Y_1, \cdots, Y_N$. The observations are identically distributed, i.e. $Y_i \sim \mathcal{P}(Y|X) $. However, they are not independent.

I would like to know, how can I estimate $\mathcal{P}(Y|X)$ given these N observations. An exemplary solution for binary symbols would be great (i.e. $X,Y \in \{0,1\}$).

```
                X
                |
-----------------------------------
|                                 | 
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
-----------------------------------
  |      |     |      |        | 
 Y_1    Y_2   Y_3    Y_4      Y_N
```

Comment: Estimate the joint conditional distribution of $(Y_1,...,Y_N)$ nonparametrically. In the simple example of binary $X,Y$: $\hat{P}(Y_1=y_1,...,Y_N=y_N|X=x)=\frac{\sum I\{Y_{1i}=y_1,...Y_{Ni}=y_N,X_i=x\}}{\sum I\{X_i=x\}}$. In the general case, you can use kernel regression. Then derive the marginal dist of $Y_i|X$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention this in my post. Consider the binary case: P(Y|X) is a 2x2 matrix (when both X and Y take values {0,1}). I want to estimate the elements of this 2x2 matrix subject to some linear constraints. I was interested  in MLE type estimation (where I could have solved some optimization w.r.t the elements of P(Y|X). Is it possible to do the same using the procedure you described?

Comment: Usual MLE requires some parametric assumption about $P$. However, you may still proceed nonparametrically with empirical distributions and nonparam. likelihood (with or without constraints). Try to google for more info.